# Display if JavaScript is enabled Multi-line string

Tags: javascript, html, noscript

I have a web page where it's content is being loaded mostly via a javascript include (loads a widget from another server).

The problem we are having, is when a customer views the page and their browser has javascript disabled, they see nothing but our supporting html text, which confuses them. (it says "Click Above to Enter our Giveaway!", but there's nothing to click).

I can do a `<noscript>` and have some generic text say "Enable javascript!", but then all the other HTML loads and the `<noscript>` text gets buried on the page and isn't clearly visible.

I'd like to have the entire page's HTML depend on if javascript is enabled or not. The simplest way that I can think of, is to have the entire page in a

```
document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML = "<someTag>PageHTMLIncludingWidgetScript</someTag>";
```

This way, the user would only see a very basic HTML frame essentially if they don't have javascript enabled, otherwise the javascript works and populates a div with it's content, and the widget loads, etc.

The issue I've run into with this, is I can't seem to get a multiple-line string like I can with Java.

```
<table>
    <hr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>Easy Ways To Enter:</strong>
            <br/>
             Entering one time unlocks additional entry opportunities!
        </td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#giveaway" title="Scroll Down To Enter Giveaway">Via Email</a></li>
                <li><a href="#giveaway" title="Scroll Down To Enter Giveaway">Via Facebook Connect (requires login)</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is an example table that would be loaded from this. If I make it a bunch of string concatenations, then I must surround each line with `' +` and this makes the page very less editable by our regular staff.

In java, I could make that entire block a single multi-line string (it would have the spaces and tabs still, but that's OK since it's html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using double quotes instead of single quotes for the string, and replacing the double quotes in the html tags with either `\"` or single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work.

```
var string = "This is a long string that I am going to \
              continue on the next line by placing \
              a back slash at the end of the previous line.";
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the page's html is rather large, and that's a lot of lines to try to add (and keep) the \ after each line. I was looking for a way around that... if at all possible..

Comment: Why not use 2 pages? First the one that the user sees `nojs.html`, then if javascript is enabled redirect them to the javascript page. if not, they stay in the `nojs.html` page asking them to enable it.